# Show graph with no value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have data in a column which can have only two values - Staff or Temporary

Right now I have only one entry as shown below -

[image]

I need to show this in a bar chart with their count as values on Y - axis.

When I plot it, It shows only Staff with its value because there is only Staff entered in the column as shown in graph -
[image]

But I need to show both the category on X-axis with Staff and Temporary mentioned and their Count on Y-axis as 70 and 0.

Is there anyway to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Add a new row as employee type temporary and value as 0 in the datasource using power query, or create a dummy table and add a temporary row and append in your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be best in this situation is to create a lookup table that you can use in a relationship. In this example you have the following two tables:

**Some Employee Data**

[image]

**Employee Type**

[image]

And a relationship created between the two tables 'Employee' to 'Employee Type'

[image]

You use the lookup table as the axis, you can then select on the Axis settings 'Show items with no data'

[image]

In the above images, both have the Axis 'Employee Type' coming from the linked table. The one on the left does not have the 'Show items with no data' option selected, the one on the right does.

If you want you can add a numerical column to the 'Employee Type' table to use 'Sort by other column' to order them in a defined order, rather than alphabetical.